# Reference to an attribute instead of getters and setters

Tags: javascript

**Question:** is it possible to have object1 providing an attribute of object2 in a way, that no getters and setters are needed? So I could do `a = object1.attribute` and `object1.attribute = a`.

**Example:** I am implementing support for dynamic aligning of the absolutely positioned HTML objects on the page. All kinds of aligns should be supported - left, right, top, bottom, horizontal center, vertical center or even evenly spaced. To reduce the amount of duplicated code, I came up with the solution to implement class `Direction`, which can be horizontal and vertical and works in the Facade-ish mode with regards to the `Element`. It this is passed as an attribute to the aligning function. Similarly, I am handling the left/right/middle and distribute evenly distinction, but to keep it simple, let's ignore it here.

Here is the class.

```
Direction = function(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
}

Direction.prototype.get = function(element) {
    return parseInt(element.style[this.selector]);
}

Direction.prototype.set = function(element, value) {
    element.style[this.selector] = value + 'px';
}
```

Here are the "constants" available to the client.

```
Direction.VERTICAL = new Direction('left');
Direction.HORIZONTAL = new Direction('top');
```

Here is the public method performing the "minimal" align (left or top).

```
alignMin = function(elements, direction) {
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(min, direction.get(elements[i]));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        direction.set(elements[i], min);
    }
}
```

And the client here demonstrates the intended use.

```
alignDivsToLeft = function() {
    alignMin(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), Direction.VERTICAL);
}
```

Working example on a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Tpam/

**Question again:** All this works, I was just wondering, if instead of `Direction.get()` and `Direction.set()` methods I could do something (a reference to a value?) to directly access the "proxified" attribute, so the `alignMin` function could use just

```
...
min = Math.min(min, direction.value);     // possibly with parseInt()
...
```

and

```
...
direction.value = min;                    // possibly with + 'px'
...
```

If there is a simple solution for this, it would be a shorter, clearer and more elegant way, especially in cases with more attributes (position, dimension, ...). Plus there is the factor of the curiosity (still learning magic of JavaScript, so..).

Comment: I get most of this question, but if you just had `min = Math.min(min, direction.value)` how does it know which element you want the min `value` from?

Comment: Equally, with `direction.value = min;` you're no longer passing a reference to which element you're trying to set.

Comment: @Jamiec Oh. That's true. So the example is not really very good to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve. Anyway, for the sake of the question, please disregard this fact and either I'll come up with some better example, or just imagine the `element` attribute was passed there "somehow" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript in some browsers supports [getters and setters as described in this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)

Using your objects:

```
Direction = function(selector) {
    this._selector = selector;
}

Direction.prototype = {
    get selector(){
        return this._selector;
    },
    set selector(selector){
        this._selector = selector
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var direction = new Direction("left");
console.log(direction.selector); // getter
direction.selector = 'right' //setter
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Tpam/1/

This would seem in the first instance to be what you're describing, but be aware it does not have global support

> Firefox
>      Safari 3+ (Brand New)
>      Opera 9.5 (Coming Soon)
>   <sub>Source: above-linked article</sub>

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was fishing for. I just couldn't google it in any way. Thanks!